# Web browser extension or software that acts like VSTS Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: manual-testing, tools, mtm, web, management

My team is currently developing a web app and I would say it is currently 80% to what reach what we really want. We are in a continual process to add new features, improve the user experience and fix bugs.

In the meantime, we want to add a QA team so that at the end of each development sprint, the QA team will perform manual functional tests on new features and also perform regression tests on existing features. I am in the midst of coming up with test cases on excel, but realised that it will too tedious for both the test plan creator and testers to do bug reporting on Excel.

I realise that Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) has all the features that we need, basically a tab at the side of browser with all the test cases, a pass/fail option, a basic bug reporting features, but the subscription is really something we can't afford yet. $52 a month per user is really too much. I wonder if there are any other test management software or tools out there that are vaguely similar to MTM, and not so expensive/free?

The features that I probably need are:

- Listing test cases
- Stated Acceptance Criteria
- Ability to attach test artifacts
- A summary page of all test cases

Features that are good to have are:

- A web browser so that I can do the web app testing easily
- Ability to add test steps
- Ability to import test cases (so that I can give the test cases at once to all my QA testers)

Comment: In my company we are using MS Excel online. Your work is saved in Onedrive and easily shared among members of the team.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of open-source project management tools available to fit the bill. I am familiar with [Redmine](https://www.redmine.org/). It is cross-platform, cross-DB, works via web interface, can be used for tracking bugs, backlog items, test cases. It has user access control so folks with different roles can have differing permissions for each action and function. 
It takes a little work to configure, but once it's up there's nothing to do but work on your project.

Others to consider:

[Testuff](https://www.testuff.com/) - $27/user/month. All data is cloud-based.

[TestLink](http://testlink.org/) - Open source, has the same functionality as Testuff but is hosted on your own hardware.

[FogBugz](https://www.fogbugz.com/index.html) - $810/year for 5 users. Great reporting functions.